# CakePHP Controller creates an empty Folder

Tags: controller, directory, addition, cakephp-2.3

I would be happy to create a folder automatically as soon as I get a new record on the "add" investing.
In addition, I would still prefer it if this is the folder would also get the ID of the record.
Is this possible?

Currently I have the following. But he puts me not even a folder.

```
$dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'images');
```

Did you maybe have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Folder constructor does not automatically create a folder on the disk, you'll have to provide a second parameter as true, see the [api](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html)

In your case this would be

```
$dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'images', true);
```

You can add a third parameter to provide the new directory with permissions